# mysql, how to batch execute many queries and knows which ones are returning rows

Tags: mysql

I have a script with 800 queries.  Most of them return nothing.

How can I modify this scripts to know which ones are returning rows only

```
SELECT * FROM `theprint_depotlive-v16`.`xmlconnect_notification_template` WHERE `name` LIKE '%1720%';
SELECT * FROM `theprint_depotlive-v16`.`xmlconnect_notification_template` WHERE `push_title` LIKE '%1720%';
SELECT * FROM `theprint_depotlive-v16`.`xmlconnect_notification_template` WHERE `message_title` LIKE '%1720%';
SELECT * FROM `theprint_depotlive-v16`.`xmlconnect_queue` WHERE `push_title` LIKE '%1720%';
SELECT * FROM `theprint_depotlive-v16`.`xmlconnect_queue` WHERE `message_title` LIKE '%1720%';
SELECT * FROM `theprint_depotlive-v16`.`xmlconnect_queue` WHERE `type` LIKE '%1720%';
SELECT * FROM `theprint_depotlive-v16`.`zizio_groupsale` WHERE `zizio_object_id` LIKE '%1720%';
SELECT * FROM `theprint_depotlive-v16`.`zizio_groupsale` WHERE `name` LIKE '%1720%';
SELECT * FROM `theprint_depotlive-v16`.`zizio_groupsale` WHERE `recurrence_child` LIKE '%1720%';
SELECT * FROM `theprint_depotlive-v16`.`zizio_groupsale` WHERE `recurrence_ancestor` LIKE '%1720%';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, which would return just the queries that have rows:

```
SELECT
  '`theprint_depotlive-v16`.`xmlconnect_notification_template`' as table,
  '`name` LIKE \'%1720%\'' as condition,
  count(*) as count
FROM `theprint_depotlive-v16`.`xmlconnect_notification_template`
WHERE `name` LIKE '%1720%'

UNION

SELECT
  '`theprint_depotlive-v16`.`xmlconnect_notification_template`' as table,
  '`push_title` LIKE \'%1720%\'' as condition,
  count(*) as count
FROM `theprint_depotlive-v16`.`xmlconnect_notification_template`
WHERE `push_title` LIKE '%1720%'

UNION

...

WHERE count > 0;
```

If your list of queries is in a table or something that can be read by mysql, you could potentially generate the above query programmatically using dynamic SQL.

Comment: ouch, that would be too difficult my script has 800 statements, is there anyway to do it more generic?

Comment: How do you run it now, and what kind of output do you get?  Just a bunch of table results one after another in a giant text file or something where you have no idea which result set links back to which original query?  Could you for instance put something like `PRINT 1;`, `PRINT 2;`, etc. between each query (which could be done automatically with a regular expression or simple batch script)?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to include a 'query identifier' as the first column of the resultset output, such as a a sequential number as a "key".

```
SELECT 1 as q, t.* FROM foo t WHERE ... ;
SELECT 2 AS q, t.* FROM foo2 t WHERE ... ;
```

(See the update to my answer to your previous question, for an example of how to include this unique value in each of the generated statements.)